# Mocked service returning Object ($$state) error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bardjs

I have been following the angular testing Play by Play on PluralSight by John Papa and Ward Bell.

I'm currently getting the following error when I run my specs.

```
AssertionError: expected { Object ($$state) } to have a property 'length'
at Assertion.assertLength (bower_components/chai/chai.js:1331:37)
at Assertion.assert (bower_components/chai/chai.js:4121:49)
at Context.<anonymous> (scripts/home/homeController.Specs.js:48:49)
```

Note that I have only included the code that I think is relevant so that I am not overloading this question with irrelevant information. If you need to see more code it's not a problem.

My code is as follows:

***homeController.js:***

```
window.app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'sidebarService',
             function ($scope, sidebarService) {

    $scope.title = 'Slapdash';
    $scope.sidebar = {
        "items": sidebarService.getSidebarItems()
    };

}])
```

***sidebarService.js:***

```
(function () {
window.app

    .service('sidebarService',['$http', function ($http) {

    this.getSidebarItems = function () {
        $http.get("http://wwww.something.com/getSidebarItems")
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
       };
   }]);
}());
```

***homeController.Specs.js:***

beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(function () {

    bard.appModule('slapdash');

    bard.inject(this, '$controller', '$q', '$rootScope')

    var mockSidebarService = {
        getSidebarItems : function(){
            return $q.when(mockSidebarMenuItems);
        }
    };

    controller = $controller('homeController', {
        $scope: scope,
        sidebarService: mockSidebarService
    });

});
```

failing spec:

```
        it('Should have items', function () {
        $rootScope.$apply();

        expect(scope.sidebar.items).to.have.length(mockSidebarMenuItems.length); // same number as mocked
        expect(sidebarService.getSidebarItems).to.have.been.calledOnce; // it's a spy

    });
```

Comment: Have you checked that `return $q.when(mockSidebarMenuItems);` actually returning items? specifically `mockSidebarMenuItems`.

Comment: well that is the problem but not the solution. It's returning an Object ($$state). I need it to return items.

Comment: @It-Z I found the answer! It took me a long time to work it out but after returning from a run and looking at it with fresh eyes it all made sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was that I was returning a result from the service not a promise.

```
    $http.get("http://wwww.something.com/getSidebarItems")
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.data; // <- returning data not promise
        });
```

When I was mocking I was using

```
var mockSidebarService = {
    getSidebarItems : function(){
        return $q.when(mockSidebarMenuItems);
    }
};
```

which mocks a promise. However I just needed to return the data as the promise was awaited in the service.

```
       mockSidebarService = {
           getMenuItems : function(){
               return mockSidebarMenuItems
           }
       };
```

I made the changes and it all works now. Took a while but at least it's making sense.